# I can't get my "if" alerts to pop up after the prompt inquire receives an answer, on JS in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement

Trying to get my if alerts to give the if or else alert pop-ups that i have down but they won't work. I've tried several ways now.

I tried refactoring it. i also had it down simply as "if (no)" and "if }else{" and nothings working.

```
<script>
      function contact() {
        let name = prompt("What is your full name?");
        let email = prompt("what is your email?");
        let inquire = prompt("Have you done yoga before?");
        if (inquire === no) {
          alert(
            `We're glad you chose us to start your journey ${name},we'll be in touch soon!`
          );
        } else {
          alert(
            `We can't wait to practice with you ${name}, we'll be in touch soon!`
          );
        }
      }
      let contactButton = document.querySelector(".contactButton");
      contactButton.addEventListener("click", contact);
    </script> here
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: You're missing quotes around no, inquire is of type string

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! simply adding quotes around no worked.

Comment: No worries! Without those quotes, your code is looking for a variable called no, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need to change this line:

```
if (inquire === no) {
```

change to
if (inquire === "no") {